# Improved Euler method for second order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I am trying to solve the simple harmonic oscillator problem with various Euler methods. Having managed to solve it with simple and modified Euler methods now I am trying to solve it with the improved Euler method which is a bit like Runge-Kutta. My concern is that when I plot the graph of energy vs. time it oscillates though it also increases at the same time. Since x(position) is actually the integral of v(velocity) is it possible to solve it numerically?

The equations I have used are as follows:

$$ \frac{dv}{dt}= a= \frac{F}{m}=-\frac{kx}{m}$$

and the following first-order equation for the position:

$$ \frac{dx}{dt}= v $$

EDIT: The initial conditions and the constants are
$$x(0) = 0, v(0) = 5,  \ \ k = m = 1,\ h=0.1, \ N=201  $$

Yet my concern is that these equations are not independent and I think the improved Euler method cannot be applied. Do you have any suggestions on how to approach the problem? I have also added the resulting graph to illustrate my point. I have updated position and velocity as follows and in the depicted order:
$$ x_{0}=x \\ x = x + hv \\ v = v - h(\frac{kx}{m} + \frac{kx_{0}}{m})/2 \\ E = (mv^2+kx^2)/2$$

[image: The resulting graph after the data is plotted.]

There must be a mistake in this implementation and I would be grateful if someone point it out or makes a suggestion.

Thanks in advance

EDIT: Latest C Implementation

```
for(i = 0; i < N ; i++)
    {
        fprintf(fp, "%f \t %f \t %f \t %f \n", x, v, E, t);
        xint = x + (h) * v;
        vint = v - (h) * k * x / m;
        v = v - (h) * ((k * x / m) + (k * xint / m)) / 2.0;
        x = x + (h) * (v + vint) / 2.0;
        E = (m * v * v + k * x * x) / 2.0;
        t += h;
    }
```

Comment: @Amzoti I am not particulary familiar with that terminology, I know of three Euler methods simple Euler, modified Euler and improved Euler which is like Runge-Kutta actually.

Comment: @Amzoti Of course I am adding them now.

Comment: @Amzoti I think I have added all the necessary constants and initial conditions you may give it a try if you wish.

Comment: You should be updating $v$ and $x$ "simultaneously" (in theory, $[x,v]$ is a vector being updated.) The error in your code is that in the line `x = x + (h) * (v + vint) / 2.0;` you use $v$ that was already updated. Keep the old value of $v$ somewhere, and use it here.

Comment: Would interchanging x and v solve the issue? No it will not; okay thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: It would not, because then you would be updating $v$ using the values of $x$ that is already updated.

Comment: BTW, a good practice is to express the update step - for any such method - in the form `x += dx; v += dv;`, where `dx,dv` are computed beforehand. This separates the process of computing the increments `dx,dv` from updating the variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works for me (using [this method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heun's_method)):

[image: solution]

This is the spreadsheet I used (energy column not shown):

[image: spreadsheet]

The prediction is plain Euler: `C2 = A2+B2*0.1`, `D2 = B2+0.1*(-A2)`.

The correction is trapezoidal: `A3 = A2+0.1/2*(B2+D2)`, `B3 = B2+0.1/2*(-A2-C2)`

And so on. The way I typed the formulas in, the prediction on line 2 refers to the same time moment as row 3, which perhaps isn't logical. It could be placed one row below. But this is a matter of spreadsheet style. The point is, the method works.

The energy does grow slowly: at the end of the plot shown above, it is $12.6$ versus initial $12.5$. But this is perfectly normal for a numerical method.

Comment: Well thanks I appreciate your effort. I will investigate it.

Comment: I have tried to implement it in C but the energy seemed to oscillate what might I be doing wrong?

Comment: @Vesnog Any sort of thing. Can you paste your code to pastebin and drop a link here?

Comment: Unfortunately that site is blocked and I cannot access it.  Editing the original post I am pasting the part of my C code including only the variable update section and energy calculation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [(velocity) Verlet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verlet_integration) (Newton-Stormer-...) [method](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/verlet-integration/info) to obtain stable energy levels over long periods of time.

There are also higher-order [geometric (or symplectic) integration methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_integrator), but they have sometimes baffling coefficients.

See the text ["Moving Stars Around"](http://www.artcompsci.org/msa/web/vol_1/v1_web/v1_web.html) or the paper by [Hairer-etal.](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.7.7106) for details.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you give explicit references for these resources?

Comment: Done. Links to 2ikipedia, stackexchange and citeseer.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
You can write your equations as first order matrix equations:
\begin{align}
\vec{\xi}\pars{t} \equiv {{\rm x}\pars{t} \choose {\rm v}\pars{t}}\,,\qquad
\totald{\vec{\xi}\pars{t}}{t} = {\cal V}\vec{\xi}\pars{t}\,,\qquad
{\cal V} \equiv \pars{%
\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 1
\\[2mm]
-\,{k \over m} & 0
\end{array}}
\end{align}

> $$
> \xi_{n + 1} = {\cal R}\xi_{n}\,,\qquad
> {\cal R} \equiv \pars{%
> \begin{array}{cc}
> 1 & \Delta t
> \\[2mm]
> -\,{k \over m}\,\Delta t & 1
> \end{array}}
> \quad\mbox{with}\quad\left\vert%
> \begin{array}{rcl}
> \quad\vec{\xi}_{n} & \equiv & \vec{\xi}\pars{t}\,,\quad t \equiv n\Delta t
> \\[2mm]
> \quad\vec{\xi}_{n + 1} & \equiv & \vec{\xi}\pars{t + \Delta t}\,,\quad\Delta t > 0
> \end{array}\right.
> $$
>   and $\ds{n = 0,1,2,\ldots}$. In order to guarantees stability we need
>   $\ds{\Delta t < \root{m \over k}}$.